# How to change border color of UIview?

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

I would like to change the border color of a uiview when it's being pressed and return to the normal border color after release. What is the best practise for doing this?

Something like the picture below:
[image]

Comment: You can use UIButton right ?

Comment: Is it possible to do as a UIview?

Comment: yes it is possible

Comment: Okey good, but how do i do it?

Comment: why you are  using a view instead of button ??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't use **UITapGestureRecognizer**. You can use **UILongPressGestureRecognizer**

**Code:**

```
   override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let view = UIView.init(frame: CGRect.init(x: 30, y: 200, width: 100, height: 40))
    self.view.addSubview(view)
    view.layer.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
    view.layer.borderWidth = 3
    let tapForView = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.toChangeColor(recognizer:)))
    tapForView.minimumPressDuration = 0.01
    view.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    view.addGestureRecognizer(tapForView)
}

@objc func toChangeColor(recognizer:UILongPressGestureRecognizer)
{
    // Apply logic for changing background color.
    let view = recognizer.view
    if recognizer.state == .began {
        view?.layer.borderColor = UIColor.orange.cgColor
        print("view began")
    }
    else if recognizer.state == .ended {
        view?.layer.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
        print("view ended")

    }

}
```

This will work perfectly.

Comment: It’s my pleasure to help you

Answer (score 1):

You can use `UILongPressGestureRecognizer` to change border color of `UIView`

Add Gesture in viewDidLoad and in handleTap function you can change border color.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let tap = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.handleTap(_:)))
    customeview.addGestureRecognizer(tap)

}

 @objc func handleTap(_ sender: UILongPressGestureRecognizer) {
    print("Hello World")

    if sender.state == .began
    {
        customeview.layer.borderColor = UIColor.yellow.cgColor
        customeview.layer.borderWidth = 3
    }
    else if sender.state == .ended
    {
            customeview.layer.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
            customeview.layer.borderWidth = 3
    }
}
```

Comment: in touch end you can change it to back

Answer (score 0):

```
let tapForView = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.ToChangeColor(recognizer:)))
                        tapForView.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
                        view.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
                        view.addGestureRecognizer(tapForView)


@objc func ToChangeColor(recognizer:UITapGestureRecognizer)
{
// Apply logic for changing background color
}
```